# How can I automatically/periodically copy a file from an FTP server to a different Ubuntu server, using that Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, periodic-task

I'm trying to get a Ubuntu server to periodically (preferably whenever it gets updated, if possible) to copy a file remotely from an FTP server to a directory on the Ubuntu server. I should note I'm not very advanced with this kind of stuff.

I of course am not doing this without a tutorial, however it doesn't cover grabbing the file from an ftp. 
What would be simplest for me is to be able to run:

```
tail -F ftp://ftp.addr.ess/files/file-i-want.txt | grep --line-buffered": <" | while read x ; do echo -ne $x | curl -X POST -d @- http://url/hook ; done
```

What I'm following has that FTP address as a local address. This is a problem, because that command returns this:

> tail: cannot open 'ftp://ftp.addr.ess/files/file-i-want.txt' for reading: No such file or directory

I've tried to run:

```
rsync username@ftp.addr.ess:XX/files/file-i-want.txt /home/ubuntu/destination
```

however this returns:

> ssh: connect to host ftp.addr.ess port XX: Connection refused.

So really if I can get rsync to run FTP instead of SSH, I figure I'd be golden. I researched it though and I can't figure out how to do this (keep in mind I'm no programmer). I originally thought the error was because I wasn't giving it a password, because I didn't know how. It might be that also, though.

This however brings me to my next issue. If it's possible to make rsync do FTP instead of SSH, how would I make it periodically do that?

Answer (score 0):

What is being updated? The remote file (my guess) or something on your server? If it's the remote file, you're out of luck unless there is mecanism/process on the remote server that can send you a notification (an email for example).

I've not used *ftp* for ages, but have a look at [this](https://blog.eduonix.com/shell-scripting/how-to-automate-ftp-transfers-in-linux-shell-scripting/) as a starting point.

A periodic task can be quite easily configured with a [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) task.